# How do I return or make null all other EventListeners if another is triggered using vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, return, addeventlistener

What I am trying to accomplish is a code that when one of the buttons is clicked, the button gains the styles listed below and all other button styles return to null.

I assume it involves a boolean statement, but perhaps I am wrong.

You'll see below that I am attempting to use my "else if" statement to establish that when the event target does not equal "button", to return everything to null. However, that is clearly not working.

I have also tried "!==" and that didn't work.

Obviously, this can be done by creating an Eventlistener unique to each button, but I wanted to figure out how to do this dynamically.

CSS:

```css
button {
  font-family: "sans-serif";
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

Here is my html:

```html
<section id="button-container">
  <button>a</button>
  <button>b</button>
  <button>c</button>
  <button>d</button>
  <button>e</button>
</section>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#button-container button');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target === button) {
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      e.target.style.color = "orange";
    } else if (e.target != button) {
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = null;
      e.target.style.color = null;
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Don't "mess" with the `style` property. Instead add a class (e.g. `.active`) to the clicked button. And before you do that, you're  removing the class from the _old_ `active` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying the `style` directly I would use a class instead:

```css
button.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: orange
}
```

When you click a button then add the `active` class to it:

```js
button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  this.classList.add("active");
});
```

We now only have to add some logic to remove the `active` class from the previously clicked button.

We could either go over all the buttons and remove the class from all of them:

```js
buttons.forEach(button => button.classList.remove("active"));
```

Or we query the DOM for the currently "active" button and remove it from that button only:

```js
const activeButton = document.querySelector("#button-container button.active");
activeButton.classList.remove("active");
```

or we use the `parentNode` from the current button to "search":

```js
const activeButton = button.parentNode.querySelector("button.active");
```

Or we use the "magic" of `.getElementsByClassName()` which returns a live collection (it will automatically update with the current set of elements with the given class) of all elements with a given CSS class:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelector('#button-container');
const activeButtons = document.querySelector("#button-container").getElementsByClassName("active");

/* ... */

button.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  if (activeButtons.length) {
    activeButtons[0].classList.remove("active");  // there should always be only _one_ active button
  }

  this.classList.add("active");
});
```

Example:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#button-container button');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const activeButton = button.parentNode.querySelector("button.active");
    if (activeButton) {
      activeButton.classList.remove("active");
    }
    
    this.classList.add("active");
  })
})
```

```css
button {
  font-family: "sans-serif";
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
}

button.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<section id="button-container">
  <button>a</button>
  <button>b</button>
  <button>c</button>
  <button>d</button>
  <button>e</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this. It is working out wonderfully. I've been working on this for the last couple of weeks, and I understand most of what you've done in the example code, but I still can't wrap my head around "if (activeButton)". What is that statement saying?

Comment: With `.querySelector("button.active")` we "look" for a button that has the class `active`. `querySelector()` will either return the first matching element or `null`. Normally I should have checked if `activeButton` is `null` (`if (activeButton === null)`) but because I'm lazy (at least sometimes^^) I used the fact that `null` is a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and an object (like a DOM node returned by `.querySelector()`) is a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). (1/2)

Comment: If `.querySelector()` finds an element that matches the given selector then `activeButton` will be an object (= truthy) and `if (activeButton)` would be the same as `if (true)`. If there isn't an element with the given class, then `activeButton` is `null` (= falsy) and `if (activeButton)` would be the same as `if (false)` (2/2)

Answer (score 1):

You have one listener per button, and so when the event occurs you are only accessing properties of that single button on which the event happened. Yet you would need to change also something that relates to the previously marked button.

I would put the listener on the container element, so you need to create only one listener, and don't need to copy it to make it apply to each button separately.

Secondly, you could also use a kind of anchor element which you move always before the button that should be "special", and then leave it to some smart CSS to do the rest.

It is any way better practice to use CSS classes instead of specific `style` property assignments in your JS code.

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#button-container');
var marker = document.querySelector('.marker');

container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') container.insertBefore(marker, e.target);
});
```

```css
button {
  font-family: "sans-serif";
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.marker+button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<section id="button-container">
  <button>a</button>
  <button>b</button>
  <button>c</button>
  <button>d</button>
  <button>e</button>
  <span class="marker" />
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to remember which one is the current one in a variable...

```
let current = null;
buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (current) {
            current.style.backgroundColor = "";
            current.style.color = "";
        }
        current = button;
        current.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        current.style.color = "blue";
    });
});
```